# MIGRATION FAILED ENUM TYPE ALREADY EXISTS ERROR

Tags: postgresql, migration, flyway

I'm building a microservices app using **Spring Boot** + **Postgres** + **Flyway**,
within *flight-archive* microservice, I created a script *sql* that contains the following code:

```
CREATE TYPE Payment_method AS ENUM ('CASH', 'PAYPAL', 'CREDIT CARD');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flight_booking_archive (
booking_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
flight_Id INT NOT NULL,
passenger_Id INT NOT NULL,
adults INT NOT NULL,
babies INT NOT NULL,
amount_paid MONEY,
payment_method Payment_method,
booked DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,

CONSTRAINT fk_flight_id FOREIGN KEY (flight_Id) references flight(flight_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_passenger_id FOREIGN KEY (passenger_Id) references passenger(passenger_ID)
```

)

then, when I run *flight-archive* microservice using maven, I got the following error

```
SQL State  : 42710
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: type "payment_method" already exists
Location   : db/migration/V1__flight_archive_table.sql (C:\Users\OMAYMA\flight-app- 
demo\server\flight-booking- 
archive\target\classes\db\migration\V1__flight_archive_table.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE TYPE Payment_method AS ENUM ('CASH', 'PAYPAL', 'CREDIT CARD')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres if you want to use uppercase you have to use quotation marks, otherwise, the words will always be in lowercase.

Try making this change:

```
CREATE TYPE "Payment_method" AS ENUM ('CASH', 'PAYPAL', 'CREDIT CARD');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flight_booking_archive (
booking_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
flight_Id INT NOT NULL,
passenger_Id INT NOT NULL,
adults INT NOT NULL,
babies INT NOT NULL,
amount_paid MONEY,
payment_method "Payment_method",
booked DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,

CONSTRAINT fk_flight_id FOREIGN KEY (flight_Id) references flight(flight_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_passenger_id FOREIGN KEY (passenger_Id) references passenger(passenger_ID)
```